# how can I compute the temperature of a metal (iron / steel) rod when a current is applied?

Tags: home-experiment, thermal-radiation

I would like to compute something like $T(j,l,R)$ where $T$ is the temperature of the rod, $j$ the current, $l$ the lenght of the rod and $R$ the radius of the rod.

there is any difference if the rod is hollowed ?

I'm interested by building an electric oven from scratch. ($T_{max} = 533.15 K,260°C,500°F$)

Comment: sure there is, heat has to diffuse from the centre to the surface so there's a temperature profile thus a resistance profile. and these profiles are very different in these two case. if you make it hollow with the same radius it would have higher resistance and thus higher power under constant current assumption but I think a constant voltage assumption would be better than constant current assumption.

Comment: You cannot compute this ab initio, heat dissipation in air is very complicated. (You can refer to existing measurements there), everything else (heat transport in the rod, changes is resistance) are tractable. Environmental temperature matters a lot, so isolate it sufficiently and you will be able to heat up a lot.

Comment: @SebastianRiese you seem to know well about this subject, do you have some books/internet links/articles (scholarly journals)/thesis references to share ?